# How do you include the number of rows in an Excel 2010 worksheet name?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Is it possible to include the number of rows in an Excel worksheet (that contain data) in the worksheet name? Currently the names look like "Widgets", I would like them to look like: "Widgets (n)" The first row is a header, so the total number of rows would be n-1. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Sub range_reporter()
  Dim r As Range
  Dim nLastRow As Long
  ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

  nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
  ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "(" & nLastRow - 1 & ")"
End Sub
```

[image]

However the count will include rows that may be empty within non-empty rows.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll need to add some things to make it run automatically and overwrite vs. append the count, but this is a great start. Dan

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could suggest would be to save through a Macro. That way you can get the row count (there is a variety of ways no doubt discussed here) and create a save string that appends the row count.

The only downside to this would be that it would create a new file each time (as the file name would change.) You could move the old ones using the same macro to an archive folder or delete them - but this would be something to bear in mind.

Hope that this helps

Comment: I disagree - the file name wouldn't change - it's the worksheet name that changes, not the workbook name.
Any links to those worksheets from external closed files would break though.